# NetLogo: Moving turtles towards patch color

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to have a turtle move towards a patch with a certain color?

i.e. have a turtle move towards red patch from blue patch?

Answer (score 2):

sure enough

ask the turtles in question to

```
face one-of patches with [pcolor = red]
fd 1
```

although you should do some exception handling because if there is not a patch of that color you will get a

> "FACE expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead. error
>   while turtle 0 running FACE   called by Agent Monitor"

error

I do it something like this

```
 let targ one-of patches with[pcolor = red]
 if targ != nobody [set heading towards targ fd 1]
```

I hope that works for what you want.

Alternately as I was reminded in the comments.

```
If any? Patches with[ pcolor = red]
[set heading towards one-of patches with[ pcolor = red ] fd 1]
```

But as Seth says in the comments that computes the red patches twice which is costly.

Comment: you can also use `if any? ...` instead of `if ... != nobody`

Comment: You are the best. Old habits die hard. I will change it

Comment: I prefer the original version, since it doesn't compute the set of red patches twice — an expensive operation.

Comment: so do I. I just forgot why I do it that way.

Comment: If i have multiple red patches the agente moves in a very odd way and not towards any patch